# How to solve an equation with a power of 5?

Tags: binomial-theorem

Let $a$ be a real constant, if $$\left(x^3 + \frac{a}{x^2}\right)^5 = -270$$what is the value of $a$ ?

Is this a type of binomial expansion question?

Comment: These are two variables and one equation, it probably isn't solvable

Comment: What is the context for this equation? @JaideepKhare is probably right - there is no solution with just the information you've written in the quesiton.

Comment: Put $x=1$ in given equation .

Comment: If the question is like sum of coefficients of binomial expression is

Comment: are you trying to find a in terms of x?

Comment: That's the entire question, and the answer is -3, I'm not sure how to solve it. This question came out in mext exams..

Comment: You can only find $a$ in terms of $x$ in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.**

By using binomial expansion, the formula is $(a+b)^5 = a^5 + 5a^4b + 10a^3b^2 + 10a^2b^3 + 5ab^4 + b^5$

Therefore: 
$$\left(x^3 + \frac{a}{x^2}\right)^5 = -270$$
$$x^{15}+5x^{10}a+10x^5a^2+10a^3+5\frac{a^4}{x^5}+\frac{a^5}{x^{10}} = -270$$

Which does not help you much, because you do not know the value of $x$, and thus the equation is unsolvable, because it contains two variables. However, it can be solved if $x$ is known. For example, if $x=1$, then you could have done it much easier:

$$5a+10a^2+10a^3+5a^4+a^5 = -271$$

Without knowing the exact value of $x$, this is clealy unsolvable.